# Switching microphone to avoid echo in webRTC

Tags: android, echo, webrtc, microphone

I am working on **webRTC**. Right now I am using **echo challenge**, so I was thinking about the **microphone toggling techniques**. For example, user A is talking by switch off the microphone of user B and vice versa. Is webRTC has this build in implemented? if not how can I achieve that ? any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC doesn't have this built in, because this is really more related to the media presentation layer. A good strategy to use, employed by [SimpleWebRTC](https://github.com/henrikjoreteg/simplewebrtc) via the [attachMediaStream](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/attachMediaStream) module is to simple attach the local participant's media with the video (or audio, for audio only) element muted.

The relevant code found in the main file of that module [here](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/attachMediaStream/blob/master/attachmediastream.js). Is this:

```
if (!element) {
    element = document.createElement(opts.audio ? 'audio' : 'video');
} else if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'audio') {
    opts.audio = true;
}

// Mute the video element so the local participant's audio doesn't play - do this only for the local participant, not the remote participants
if (opts.muted) element.muted = true;

// attach the stream to the element
if (typeof element.srcObject !== 'undefined') {
    element.srcObject = stream;
}
```